# Entity Framework tries to create user when adding other object to db

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I'm trying to create an address and I get a weird exception like so:

> Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'LoweredUserName', table 'SkiShop.dbo.aspnet_Users'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.
>       The statement has been terminated.

I thought ok, perhaps there's a stray user having been created but not comitted but nope, a `db.saveChanges()` call before trying to create and add the address goes fine!

Here's my code (using ASP.NET MVC 2):

```
var userId = Helpers.CreateAspNetUserFromUser(employee.aspnet_Users, employee.TempPass);
try {
    db.SaveChanges(); //no probs
}
catch (Exception) {

    throw; // doesn't land here
}


if (userId != null) {
    employee.AspNetUserId = (Guid)userId;
    try
    {
        employee.TempPass = null;
        Address address = employee.Address;
        address.CreatedById = employee.CreatedById;
        address.ModifiedById = employee.CreatedById;
        address.DateCreated = employee.DateCreated;
        address.DateModified = employee.DateModified;

        db.Addresses.AddObject(address);
        db.SaveChanges(); //throws exception here
```

Why is it trying to create a user again? If it's a false error message I'm confused because the foreign keys for address are all ok, and all the properties for Address are also all ok and match database specs.

Edit: Here are the create table statements:

```
CREATE TABLE [Address] (
    AddressId int primary key identity(1,1) not null,
    Street nvarchar(128) not null,
    HouseNr nvarchar(8) not null,
    PostCode nvarchar(128) null,
    [State] nvarchar(128) not null,
    Country nvarchar(128) not null,
    Telephone nvarchar(128) not null,

    --Relationships & auditing
    CreatedById uniqueidentifier not null,
    ModifiedById uniqueidentifier not null,
    DateCreated datetime not null,
    DateModified datetime not null,

    Constraint fk_address_cb Foreign Key (CreatedById) References Aspnet_Users(UserId),
    Constraint fk_address_mb Foreign Key (ModifiedById) References Aspnet_Users(UserId),
);

CREATE TABLE Employee (
    SvnNr nvarchar(16) primary key not null,
    DOB date not null,

    --Relationships & auditing
    AddressId int not null,
    AspNetUserId uniqueidentifier not null,
    CreatedById uniqueidentifier not null,
    ModifiedById uniqueidentifier not null,
    DateCreated datetime not null,
    DateModified datetime not null,
    TempPass nvarchar(max) null,

    Constraint fk_employee_address Foreign Key (AddressId) References [Address](AddressId),
    Constraint fk_employee_user Foreign Key (AspNetUserId) References Aspnet_Users(UserId),
    Constraint fk_employee_cb Foreign Key (CreatedById) References Aspnet_Users(UserId),
    Constraint fk_employee_mb Foreign Key (ModifiedById) References Aspnet_Users(UserId),
);
```

Comment: It may be helpful to see `Address` and `Employee` class definitions.

Comment: @qbik - i'm working with db first so I'll put up the create table statements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Why is it trying to create a user again?` Because you have `fk_employee_user` in your database design and EF reflects it. When you instantiate `Employee`, .Net creates a null user object for `Employee` too. These created objects are just instant of objects and their most properties are null. To circumvent of that, before saving your `Address` and `Employee`, do something like

> Employee.User=null;

In that case EF never try to save user for `Employer` . Be sure you have your desired userId in your `Employee` object.

Comment: Ugh, I was only adding the createdBy and modifiedBy aspnet_users :-(